# OBD2 reader goes to sleep mode

Tags: can-bus, obd-ii

I am creating software, where I need to receive and transmit messages via bluetooth to OBD2 reader (I am using Quicklynks BLE327 Blackbox). The reader isn't connected to any vehicle, it's on my desk and I have power and CAN cables connected to it. I can't get started properly, because when I try to make a bluetooth connection to reader, it goes to sleep mode before I can properly even try to make a connection.

So the problem is that I can't find any information what message I should be transmitting via CAN to the reader so it would stay awake.

Thank you already!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question sounds rather [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Have you asked the supplier/manufacturer of your hardware about your issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the use of one particular electrical product and not about programming.